# Singular vs plural as descriptor

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns

> 1) we are **friend** since we were **a child**
>
> 2) We are **friends** since we were **a child**
>
> 3) We are **friends** since we were **children**

First of all, I am sorry if these sentences are awkward since I wrote it myself. So, from these three sentences which one is correct if I want to say that my friend and I are friends since childhood?

Comment: It would also be better to use the past perfect tense: "We **have been** friends since..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *people* are plural, but there is a singular *relationship* between the people.  When using nouns that refer directly to the people, you should use the plural:

> We have been **friends** since we were **children**.

When using nouns that refer to the relationship between the people or to the shared state of being children, then you use the singular:

> We have shared a **friendship** since **childhood**.

Note that in both cases, the present perfect tense is a better fit than the present tense, since you are referring to a state of being that began in the past and has continued through the present.

Answer (score 1):

As we are talking about 2 people (plural) so 3rd is correct.
"We are **friends** since we were **children**"